# TF14092:A parent of this item has a pending delete which must be checked in first

Tags: tfs, nuget

When I am trying to update our internal packages using NuGet . I am facing the TF14092:TF14092:A parent of this item has a pending delete which must be checked in first.

Any thoughts?

Comment: First thought: Did you check to see if you have pending deletes?

Comment: No, I don't have anything in pending delete